# Python/Scikit-learn - How to actually predict?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have the following DataFrame, which I call main_frame:

```
               Value     Value      1lag      2lag      3lag      4lag 
Date                                                                     
2005-04-01  0.824427  0.892308  1.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000   
2005-05-01  0.778626  0.953846  0.892308  1.000000  0.000000  0.000000   
2005-06-01  0.717557  1.000000  0.953846  0.892308  1.000000  0.000000   
2005-07-01  0.725191  0.000000  1.000000  0.953846  0.892308  1.000000   
2005-08-01  0.717557  1.000000  0.000000  1.000000  0.953846  0.892308   
2005-09-01  0.740458  0.861538  1.000000  0.000000  1.000000  0.953846   
2005-10-01  0.732824  0.877193  0.861538  1.000000  0.000000  1.000000   
2005-11-01  0.732824  1.000000  0.877193  0.861538  1.000000  0.000000   
2005-12-01  0.641221  1.000000  1.000000  0.877193  0.861538  1.000000   
2006-01-01  0.709924  0.614035  1.000000  1.000000  0.877193  0.861538   
2006-02-01  0.770992  0.649123  0.614035  1.000000  1.000000  0.877193
```

I've built the following model:

```
predictor=main_frame.iloc[:,1:]
target=main_frame.iloc[:,0]

model=LinearRegression()
model.fit(X=predictor,y=target)
```

I know that to predict, I should use now model.predict(), however I'm having a hard time to understand how does the arguments of the predict function work. I'm trying to use:

```
prediction=model.predict(target)
print predict
```

But that keeps getting me an error, I believe that I'm misunderstanding something related to the argument.

How do I set up the command for the prediction to work?

**EDIT**

I'm adding the Traceback

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py:386:     DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17 and willraise ValueError in 0.19. Reshape your data either using X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
DeprecationWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/file.py", line 61, in <module>
prediction=model.predict(target)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/base.py", line 200, in predict
return self._decision_function(X)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/base.py", line 185, in _decision_function
dense_output=True) + self.intercept_
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/extmath.py", line 184, in safe_sparse_dot
return fast_dot(a, b)
ValueError: shapes (1,127) and (144,) not aligned: 127 (dim 1) != 144 (dim 0)
```

**EDIT 2**

Trying to put my question in other words so it gets better to be answered:

> Considering the above model, how do I find out what is going to be the predicted value for the next period for the target variable?

Comment: print prediction ? (predict is not defined)

Comment: Don't just say "an error".  Always include the complete error message in your question.

Comment: Your shouldn't predict based on data from `target` but from new samples (what you called `predictor` before)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the wrong argument into the predict function. Try this:

```
prediction=model.predict(predictor)
print prediction
```

Note that the model has been trained using the "predictor" variable. So you can only predict data that have the exact same amount of columns as the "predictor" variable.

Comment: Thanks. However prediction is getting me a long array and all I want is to find out the predicted value for the n+1 period. How do I find that out?

Comment: You will need to pass in the predictor values for the n+1 period. So you will need to get the column values of the second Value column, 1lag, 2lag, 3lag and 4lag columns. Then the model can give you the predicted value for the first Value column.

So with the data in your example, you should train the model with all the rows except for the last one (so everything except period 2006-02-01). Then you use your model to only predict that last row.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was the missing detail I couldn't find anywhere. So that long array that I was getting inside "prediction" is the prediction value for each period considering the regression that the fit has created, right?